# Spring Config for Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, spring, configuration, sessionfactory, hibernate-session

Hi
I'm trying to obtain hibernate's Session through Spring's injection.

Here's my spring context xml:

```
  <!-- hibernate's session factory -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
      <value>classpath:./hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- the transaction manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
```

Here's the code:

```
private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    if (ctx == null) {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springContext.xml");
    }
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sf = ctx.getBean(LocalSessionFactoryBean.class);
    session = sf.getObject().getCurrentSession();
```

However the session I obtain is null.

Is it correct to get Session through sf.getObject().getCurrentSession() ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should access the session like that. Either use [`HibernateTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) or inject `SessionFactory` in your beans and call `getCurrentSession()` on it. Otherwise your transaction management won't be handled properly